# Trying to use the DATETIME in SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to use the `DATETIME` in SQL to get information from another table. I have been trying to figure out how a blasted FUNCTION works and it's syntax for 2 hours now. So as you can tell I'm not very prolific or fluent in the language or syntax.

Could you please help me spot my error and correct me, much appreciated. Here is the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PetFunction (@PETVAT int)
    RETURNS INT
    AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @VATID int
    SET @VATID = 0
    SELECT @VATID = [ID](*Invalid column name 'ID'*.) 
      FROM dbo.VAT(*Invalid object name*.) 
    WHERE VATBeginDate(*Invalid Column name*.) > DATETIME(*Invalid column name*.) 
    AND VATEndDate(*Invalid column name*.) < DATETIME(*Invalid column name*.) =(*Incorrect syntax newr '='*) @PETVAT

    RETURN @VATID
    END
```

I marked the error messages next to the words that are throwing these errors, and I marked it in Italic. I have only 2 tables which are dbo.PETS and dbo.VAT.

PETS columns:

```
PetType, Stock, Sold, VATID, SoldPrice, 
PurchaseDateSupplier, SoldDateClient and SalesPerson.
```

VAT columns:

```
VATBeginDate VATEnddate and VAT
```

So here are whats in each table with a line of data in each:

dbo.PETS:

```
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+----------------------+----------------+-------------+
| ID | PetType | Stock | Sold  | VATID | SoldPrice | PurchaseDateSupplier | SoldDateClient | SalerPerson |
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+----------------------+----------------+-------------+
|  2 | Cat     |     3 |     2 |     1 |   1500.00 | 2018-02-04           | 2018-02-07     | Sammy       |
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+----------------------+----------------+-------------+
```

dbo.VAT:

```
+----+--------------+------------+------+
| ID | VATBeginDate | VATEnddate | VAT  |
+----+--------------+------------+------+
|  1 | 2017-01-01   | 2018-01-01 | 0.14 |
+----+--------------+------------+------+
```

I am trying to take the ID column value in `dbo.VAT` and insert it into the VATID cell in `dbo.PETS`, so if the current date is more than 2018-01-01 then it should enter ID 2 which would be a new line in the `dbo.VAT` table where VAT is increased to 0.15 (Due to the VAT change recently in South Africa, I want it to be dynamic to "Future Proof" this feature so if it changes again all you do is insert the new VAT into the `dbo.VAT` table and the rest are done automatically while older pets that were sold is still on record at the correct VAT price for when they were sold.

This is just a small project I'm doing to help teach myself some SQL.

Thank for any help.

Comment: share your complete code which is giving error? DATETIME is not a function in SQL SERVER.

Comment: Eben - can you share (at the end of your post or in comment), what you are trying to get to?  What info is in that VAT table?  VATID is in PETS, but not VAT.  Is the "id" for that VAT table "VAT"?  Typically - we'd use a uniqe ID that both tables share to "join" them and get a value.

Comment: I think what you are intending to do is `CAST` or `CONVERT` the values to datetime values (a data type, not a function). Look up these two functions and that might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Pawan Kumar,

That is all the code i have written so far excluding making the tables and columns, i will now attempt to add the table columns and add a line of what is in each table and what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: The columns you posted does not match with what you are using in the function above. Where does the ID column belong?. Please update your schema to include all columns.

Comment: Eben - how did this work out for you?  Did the anwer resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for going AWOL. I never figured out how to get this to work so i dropped this and moved on to another practice project. I am supposed to meet with someone who will explain these things to me in person and demonstrate it as well sometime soon, thank you all for your help and suggestion and again, sorry for disappearing.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to make a couple of quick assumptions about what you are asking.

1. I assume that each table you've listed actually has a primary key called ID (that's what it looks like you are trying to pull from VAT)
2. I assume you are trying to pull the correct VATID from VAT based on the SoldDateClient from PETS

If that's true, then I'd just change up the meat of your function like this:

```
 DECLARE @ID INT, @Dt DATETIME
 SELECT @Dt=SoldDateClient FROM Pets WHERE ID=@PETID
 SELECT @ID=ID
    FROM VAT
    WHERE VATBeginDate >= @Dt 
       AND VATEndDate <= @Dt
 RETURN @ID
```

FYI - If the goal is to use this function to populate the VATID column in PETS, then you might be able to skip using a function, and just use an update statement.

```
UPDATE PETS 
   SET VATID=V.ID
   FROM PETS P
      INNER JOIN VAT V ON P.SoldDateClient>=V.VATBeginDate 
         AND P.SoldDateClient<V.VatEndDate
   WHERE P.ID=1234
```

Note, however, that any overlapping dates in your VAT table are going to cause you problems.  So - make sure that there is 1 and only 1 record per VAT date range if you decide to try that.

Of course - anyone who's got mad SQL skills will come in and edit that update statement to account for multiple records... And downvote my initial answer (depending on their mood at the time).

Comment: Haha, this looks correct, ill try it now to see how it works, im trying to "automate" it so that it automatically does this each time a new line is inserted into the PETS table it automatically goes and gets the correct VAT from the sbo.VAT table and populaes the VATID column in PETS table based on date ranges yes. That is why i was told to maybe use a function for this and as such, why i tried to make a function

Comment: Computed column.  Got it.  As those tables scale up, that computed column gets a little expensive (executes a statement for every row each time you run a SELECT query).  Just FYI.  If you're doing this for a 20K row table, who cares.  If it's a 20M row table, then it'll slow things down.  Look at an INSERT/UPDATE trigger as an alternative (although we mostly do this sorta thing in the application so that there isn't business logic buried in the DB).